# Is there a way to get the trigger time from a celery task?

Tags: python-3.x, django, celery, django-celery, django-celery-beat

Let's assume a situation that there is a celery beat task that is scheduled to run every 15 minutes. Now a "celery beat process" schedules it as per the system clock and the "celery workers" consume from the queue in which "celery beat" produces those tasks. Now there can be a delay in the time that the worker picks up the task to be executed and the time that the task was intended to run. How do I get this trigger time?

For example let's say beat schedules a task every 15 minutes `8:00 AM`, `8:15 AM`, `8:30 AM`, and so on. The worker picks up the `8:30` task at about `8:51 PM` and thus if I try to get the time in the task code I will get `8:51 AM` instead of `8:30 AM`. Is there any parameter that can allow me to get this `8:30 AM` trigger time from within the task?

Comment: I'm using Redis as the broker and celery 4.3.0